# Can instances get their own copy of class level mutable defaults without using __init__?

Tags: class, python-3.x, default-value, mutable, metaclass

I'm writing a metaclass to do some cool stuff, and part of its processing is to check that certain attributes exist when the class is created.  Some of these are mutable, and would normally be set in `__init__`, but since `__init__` isn't run until the instance is created the metaclass won't know that the attribute *will* be created, and raises an error.  I could do something like:

```
class Test(meta=Meta):
    mutable = None
    def __init__(self):
        self.mutable = list()
```

But this approach has several problems:

- it forces the creation of a class attribute that is not the same type as the instance attribute
- `__init__` still has to shadow the class attribute, and `Meta` is not checking that
- if `__init__` doesn't shadow the class attribute I'll still get errors down the line (such as `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'`), and trying to avoid such errors is part of the function of `Meta`
- and last but not least, it violates DRY.

What I need is a way to have something like:

```
class Test(metaclass=Meta):
    mutable = list()
```

But each instance will end up with its own copy of `mutable`.

The design goals are:

- the attribute must exist in the class (type doesn't matter -- it is not checked)
- at some point before the attribute is first used a copy of the attribute is placed in the instance

A desired sample run:

```
t1 = Test()
t2 = Test()
t1.mutable.append('one')
t2.mutable.append('two')
t1.mutable  # prints ['one']
t2.mutable  # prints ['two']
```

Any ideas on how this can be accomplished?

Comment: You cannot, except by making the metaclass generate an `__init__` that uses the `copy` module -- and even then it's fragile and hacky. The real problem is that the metaclass checks for instance attributes in the wrong place (the class) - why?

Comment: That's hardly a violation of DRY. :-) It's fine, go with it. Or stop checking things. EAFP :-)

Comment: @delnan: Sure I can.  And it's checking so it can catch errors of forgotten but required attributes at class creation, instead of further down the line when the attribute is used (raising an `AttributeError`).

Comment: But what's the point if it either prevents instance attributes or requires you to provide bogus class-level data? The latter may even lead to errors not causing an `AttributeError` but silently leading to wrong results!

Comment: @delnan: My solution does not prevent instance atributes, and the class-level data is no more bogus than any other `property`-style attribute.

Comment: The question indicates otherwise. And in the case of `property`, the class attribute is of a completely unlikely type which causes errors in almost all operations.

Comment: @delnan: I think you dropped a word or two in your last comment -- I don't understand.

Comment: Yes, just noticed and fixed it.

Comment: @delnan: I have not had experience with troubles caused by `property` -- if you have examples please create an answer detailing;  you'll have my vote, at least.

Comment: My point is that `property` does *not* cause trouble (in response to your claim that your bogus class-level data is akin to `property` et al). It inserts an object (of the same name as the instance attribute being simulated) into the class, but this object cannot be confused with the instance-level data. In your case, you force yourself to provide some data for that attribute (because, as I've said before, **your metaclass seems to check the wrong place!**) and you're likely to provide something that *can* be confused with genuine instance data, masking errors.

Comment: @delnan: I don't think you understand what the code is actually doing.  The data provided is *not* bogus -- it is what will be the instance level attribute; a class-level access will not see it.  Updating my answer to hopefully explain that a little better...

Comment: `mutable = None` is clearly bogus. So your code checks that mutable is there, but can't check that it is a list, because the list hasn't been created. This provides no actual benefit. You aren't checking anything useful. Instead you force the class implementor to add a useless `mutable = None` to avoid getting an error by a check that doesn't check what needs to be checked.

Comment: And why is it better to check at class creation than later? What benefit does that get you? Class creation is still runtime...

Comment: @LennartRegebro: That first code sample is what I *don't* want to do, and it is not present in my answer.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: It's better to check at class creation because the exception is raised where the error is located, not somewhere else.

Comment: @delnan: Were you thinking the same thing as Lennart?  That the first code sample is what I was proposing as the solution?  --  **\*shudder\*** --  No, that's what I want to get away from.

Comment: @EthanFurman I'm still waiting for that clarifying update to the question. As it stands now, I still read your question as "My metaclass requires that certain instance attributes are present and checks this by querying for class attributes - how do I make it happy?". It seems pretty obvious that the metaclass is doing it wrong. I see the first code snippet as a horrible workaround to that problem, which I critizise for reasons already enumerated. I propose that you fix the obviously broken behaviour of the metaclass instead.

Comment: I know that's what you want to get away from. But with your metaclass **you can't**. But since the check your metaclass does **is pointless** you can skip it: Problem solved.

Comment: @delnan: I said I was updating my answer, and you are waiting for an update to the question?  I asked for a way to replace the first code snippet (which I already know is horrible -- that's why I want to replace it), and instead of trying to find a good solution, or create an answer detailing why a good solution does not exist, all you've done is tell me why the first snippet is horrible?  All this time I've been talking about ways around the problem, and you've been talking about all the ways the problem is a problem.  Frustrating.  On the bright side: your comments make a lot more sense now.

Comment: @LennartRegebro:  You say I can't, and yet in my answer I show how it can be done with a decorator that replaces the mutable attribute with a [non-data descriptor](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) which allows each instance to get their own default mutable attribute on first access.  You say the check is pointless -- our opinions differ on this:  I think there are situations where LBYL is appropriate, and that this is one of those times.

Comment: Your answer isn't using a metaclass to check if the attribute exists, it is using a decorator to **make sure** that the attribute exists. This is not LBYL, and the solution in fact has nothing to do with your original question and does *not* check on instance creation. It also does not solve the question you posed, namely how to make sure that an object has a specific attribute be a specific type any more than setting that attribute in __init__. Your solution works, but so does `def __init__(self): self.mutable = []`. There is no improvement.

Comment: Using the decorator you supply means you can have a metaclass to check  it. But then you require the users of your library to 1. Use that metaclass. 2. Use that decorator on a function they make that returns a list. Instead of doing that you could: a. require your users to do `self.mutable = list` in the __init__.py, or I. check that mutable is a list before using the instance. All of these are simpler and easier on your library users, use no magic and are way more Pythonic. It is not the problem that is the problem. It is your "solution" ie the metaclass that is the problem.

Comment: @LennartRegebro: Thank you.  My answer doesn't show the metaclass because it is a given:  It's there, it checks.  Yes, the decorator makes sure it exists -- that's the point of it.  No, my question did not ask about making sure the attribute was a specific type, only that it existed.  No, I did not require the check to be at instance creation, and in fact I prefer the check be at class creation.  If someone is using my library, it's for the metaclass, and the decorator as an aid, not the other way around.

Comment: Since it will require you to replace simple attribute assignments with decorated functions, I highly doubt it will aid anything. If you are looking at various ways of making libraries that help in making sure objects fulfill interfaces etc, there are several of those already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three ways to do this:

1. Have the metaclass check all the attributes, and if they are one of the mutables (`list`, `dict`, `set`, etc.) replace the attribute with a descriptor that will activate on first access and update the instance with a fresh copy of the mutable.
2. Provide the descriptor from (1) as a decorator to be used when writing the class.
3. Have the metaclass add its own `__init__` method to the class which when run:

   - calls the original `__init__`
   - then checks that the required attributes are present

Downsides (by method):

1. Extra effort is required if the class has a mutable attribute that *should* be shared across all instances.
2. The attribute in the class becomes a function in the class (possible mind-warp ;)
3. Move the point of error to class instantiation instead of class definition.

I prefer (2) is it gives complete control to the class author, simplifies those cases where the class-level mutable attribute *should* be shared amongst all the instances, and keeps the error at class definition.

Here's the decorator-descriptor:

```
class ReplaceMutable:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self):
        return self
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        result = self.func()
        setattr(instance, self.func.__name__, result)
        return result
```

and the test class:

```
class Test:
    @ReplaceMutable
    def mutable():
        return list()
```

How it works:

Just like `property`, `ReplaceMutable` is a descriptor object with the same name as the attribute it is replacing.  Unlike `property`, it does not define `__set__` nor `__delete__`, so when code tries to rebind the name (`mutable` in the test above) in the instance Python will allow it to do so.  This is the same idea behind caching descriptors.

`ReplaceMutable` is decorating a function (with the name of the desired attribute) that simply returns whatever the instance level attribute should be initialized with (an empty `list` in the example above).  So the first time the attribute is looked up on an instance it will not be found in the instance dictionary and Python will activate the descriptor; the descriptor then calls the function to retrieve the initial object/data/whatever, stores it in the instance, and then returns it.  The next time that attribute is accessed *on that instance* it will be in the instance dictionary, and that is what will be used.

Sample code:

```
t1 = Test()
t2 = Test()
t1.mutable.append('one')
t2.mutable.append('two')
print(t1.mutable)
print(t2.mutable)
```